# Saving Pytorch model.state_dict() to s3

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to save a trained Pytorch model to S3. However, the `torch.save(model.state_dict(), file_name)` seems to support only local files. How can the state dict be saved to an S3 file?

I'm using Torch `0.4.0`

Answer (score 3):

As discussed by [Soumith Chintala](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/20822#issuecomment-578805180), Pytorch doesn't have custom APIs to do this job. However you can use boto3 or Petastorm library to solve the problem.

Here's a concrete example to write to an S3 object directly:

```
import boto3

# Convert your existing model to JSON
saved_model = model.to_json()

# Write JSON object to S3 as "model.json"
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.put_object(Body=saved_model,
                  Bucket='BUCKET_NAME',
                  Key='model.json')
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to serialize your model state_dict via Pytorch into bytes and the write bytes to S3. To then read your model you can again use Pytorch. I prefer this option, since Pytorch Tensors are currently not JSON serializable and this way I can save any Pytorch entities to S3 without taking care of JSON conversion.

### Example code of storage:

```
import io
import boto3
import torch

# create Model
feature_size = 3
num_hidden_units = 5
num_classes = 2
model = LSTM(feature_size, num_hidden_units, num_classes)

# some additional params and a Pytorch Model state_dict
pipeline = {
    'creation_params': {
        'feature_size': feature_size,
        'hidden_size': num_hidden_units,
        'output_size': num_classes
    },
    'model': model.state_dict(),
}

# use torch to write to buffer
buffer = io.BytesIO()
torch.save(pipeline, buffer)

# create boto3 s3 client
client = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id=s3_service_key["access_key_id"],
            aws_secret_access_key=s3_service_key["secret_access_key"],
            region_name=s3_service_key["region"]).client("s3")
bucket = s3_service_key["bucket"]

# write to S3
file_name = 'my_pipeline.pipe'
client.put_object(Body=buffer.getvalue(),
                  Bucket=bucket,
                  Key=file_name)

# read from S3
object = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_name)

# use torch to load from buffer
loaded_buffer = io.BytesIO(object['Body'].read())
loaded_pipeline = torch.load(loaded_buffer)
loaded_pipeline
```

### Custom Pytorch LSTM model used in the example:

```
import torch

class LSTM(torch.nn.Module):
    """Pytorch Long Short Term Memory Model"""
    
    def __init__(self, input_size: int, hidden_units: int, output_size: int) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_units = hidden_units
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.num_layers = 1

        self.lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(
            input_size=self.input_size,
            hidden_size=self.hidden_units,
            batch_first=True,
            num_layers=self.num_layers
        )

        # Fully Connected head.
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=self.hidden_units, out_features=self.output_size)
```

### Expected output:

```
{'creation_params': {'feature_size': 3, 'hidden_size': 5, 'output_size': 2},
 'model': OrderedDict([('lstm.weight_ih_l0',
               tensor([[-0.0795,  0.4327,  0.0015],
                       [ 0.2078,  0.0112, -0.1571],
                       [ 0.3968, -0.2665,  0.2933],
                       [-0.0215,  0.1247, -0.0110],
                       [ 0.2718, -0.0490, -0.3527],
                       [-0.0973,  0.0203,  0.3735],
                       [ 0.2463,  0.3934, -0.1920],
                       [ 0.2417,  0.0767, -0.3266],
                       [ 0.4353,  0.1871, -0.1330],
                       [-0.3765, -0.2853, -0.0431],
                       [ 0.1018, -0.2759,  0.3183],
                       [-0.4396, -0.3976, -0.3267],
                       [-0.0793,  0.0422, -0.1580],
                       [-0.0177, -0.2108,  0.4165],
                       [-0.4386,  0.0810, -0.1010],
                       [-0.1727,  0.4073,  0.1428],
                       [ 0.1895,  0.3080, -0.2649],
                       [-0.1168,  0.0513, -0.4125],
                       [ 0.0222,  0.2155, -0.3811],
                       [ 0.4115,  0.0705,  0.0779]])),
              ('lstm.weight_hh_l0',
               tensor([[ 0.0748, -0.2302,  0.1061, -0.4032, -0.0811],
                       [ 0.1665, -0.4047,  0.2739,  0.2083, -0.0950],
                       [ 0.4207, -0.0352,  0.3390,  0.1517,  0.1513],
                       [ 0.3888,  0.0071,  0.3540,  0.1564,  0.0551],
                       [ 0.3667, -0.2248, -0.3964,  0.0415, -0.0252],
                       [-0.1406, -0.2868, -0.0482, -0.0604, -0.0340],
                       [ 0.0005,  0.4368,  0.1779,  0.3059,  0.2655],
                       [-0.2982, -0.1969,  0.2071, -0.3325, -0.0820],
                       [ 0.1031,  0.0054, -0.2061,  0.0545,  0.3621],
                       [-0.1067,  0.4236,  0.1288,  0.4370, -0.3919],
                       [ 0.2583,  0.4130, -0.1354,  0.0531, -0.1137],
                       [-0.1066,  0.1636,  0.0951,  0.2048, -0.2388],
                       [-0.1507, -0.1089, -0.0353,  0.0752,  0.0260],
                       [-0.1118, -0.1667,  0.1880, -0.1514,  0.2131],
                       [-0.2353,  0.3646, -0.0782,  0.0149,  0.2652],
                       [ 0.3376, -0.0620,  0.3047,  0.1078,  0.3634],
                       [-0.3960,  0.2202, -0.3784, -0.3984, -0.2837],
                       [-0.3522,  0.1816, -0.2951, -0.3113,  0.4339],
                       [ 0.1152, -0.2174,  0.2064,  0.1719, -0.1454],
                       [-0.2030, -0.2185, -0.4422,  0.2529, -0.0507]])),
              ('lstm.bias_ih_l0',
               tensor([ 0.1037, -0.4442, -0.3057, -0.2626,  0.4247, -0.4168, -0.3074, -0.2486,
                       -0.2543, -0.2585, -0.0434,  0.0484,  0.2209,  0.0836, -0.1577, -0.3079,
                       -0.1197,  0.2845, -0.0651,  0.2066])),
              ('lstm.bias_hh_l0',
               tensor([ 0.2080, -0.2914, -0.0469, -0.3911,  0.1552,  0.1993, -0.4193, -0.3178,
                        0.3968,  0.2572, -0.0280,  0.3070, -0.0320, -0.2316, -0.3241,  0.2799,
                       -0.1707, -0.0310,  0.1724,  0.2424])),
              ('linear.weight',
               tensor([[-0.1359, -0.3276, -0.3941, -0.1490, -0.0181],
                       [-0.4019,  0.0465, -0.1079,  0.3951, -0.1639]])),
              ('linear.bias', tensor([-0.2554, -0.3934]))])}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).